# MVC Spring form error Tomcat

Tags: java, forms, spring, tomcat, maven

Am getting this error when trying to open this jsp page via controller :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-     INF/jsp/rate.jsp at line 12

9:  <body>
10:         <h1>Exchange Rate</h1>
11:         <form:form method="POST" action="/rate">
12:             <form:label path="CurrencyCodeFirst">From Currency:</form:label>
13:             <form:input path="CurrencyCodeFirst"></form:input>
14:             
15:
```

Comment: Show us all the jps, sometimes the line reference is not correct

Comment: Please post the complete jsp (at least the header) and the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I bet that path `CurrencyCodeFirst` is wrong and should be `currencyCodeFirst` (notice the lowercase starting letter).